# What is the frequency of Winter-Bash Leaderboard updating?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018, winterbash-leaderboard

I noticed an anomaly in the Physics [Winter-Bash 2018 leaderboard](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/leaderboard), relevant image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aegxS.jpg), with the ["leader"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4lQb.jpg) being 3 hats behind the [second runner up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE02U.jpg).

(*Checked by going to profile pages, yes I am jobless*!)

This prompts the questions:

- Is the Winter Bash 2018 leaderboard updated in real time? Is this actual instantaneous data?
- If not, what is the update frequency for this leaderboard?

Comment: probably 6 to 8 something

Comment: @rene - Haha. Microseconds, or hours, or weeks?

Comment: you pick. Let's hope it is not [weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514) ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cache time is five minutes, but a stale cache may be served for up to an hour. That means if the cached data is less than an hour old, you'll get an immediate response with that data, and an update will be triggered in the background.

So if you wait for a moment and then reload the page, you should get fresh data (or at least data that's not older than five minutes).